# Vuforia give wrong target name

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, vuforia

I use Vuforia 5 version and starter licence key to recognize image targets.
I published my app on AppStore and it has worked for 2 weeks. But 4 days ago,
I created new xml and dat file from vuforia and my app read the target with wrong name (i think it gives random name).
My image name is like 12_02_2014 etc. And my images like each other.
I have never see the error like that, and I dont know what I am doing.
Did anyone see this error before?
I guess it is vuforia's fault.
Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Maybe it still uses the old dat/xml files?

Comment: Thanks Vrasidas. I could not realize but I used ex .dat and .xml because STORAGE_APP type.